# What is the difference between javax.faces-2.1.14.jar from jsf-api-2.2.0-m05.jar and jsf-impl-2.2.0-m05.jar

Tags: java, jsf-2

I am confused between the difference of javax.faces-2.1.14.jar from jsf-api-2.2.0-m05.jar and jsf-impl-2.2.0-m05.jar
I am trying to make a jsf project without using maven and while searching for examples I saw different jar dependencies on different tutorials.  The tutorial from [coreservlets](http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/jsf2/) uses javax.faces-2.1.14.jar and the other tutorial I saw from a different site uses 2 jar files jsf-api-2.2.0-m05.jar and jsf-impl-2.2.0-m05.jar
Id like to know the difference of these two set of dependencies.
Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `jsf-api-xxx.jar` contains classes that are under packages java package `javax.faces`. The classes in this jar are implementation of standard API defined by JSF specification. The `jsf-impl-xxx.jar` contains classes that are under java package `com.sun.faces`, which as the java package indicates, is Sun's own class for JSF implementation.

The `javax.faces-xxx.jar` actually merges the previous two jar files together. In the Maven repository, it is under `org.glassfish` groupId. You will find both `javax.faces` and `com.sun.faces` java package inside.

So what should you use for your development? Actually you can use both. But the recommended way is to include `jsf-api-xxx.jar` only in the compilation classpath. Thus your own application does not depend on any classes under `com.sun.faces` package to achieve the **portability** to other JSF implementations. If you are using an application such as GlassFish, the container should already provide the JSF implementation at runtime. You should not package the above JSF jar files with your war or ear file, as server will provide all of them. If you use a container that does not come with a JSF implementation by default such as Tomcat, you need to package `javax.faces-xxx.jar` or (`jsf-api-xxx.jar` + `jsf-impl-xxx.jar`) in the `WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: That was the kind of description and comparison I was looking for.  Also the use case especially the last paragraph is exactly the question that was bothering me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

They are different versions.

- javax.faces-2.1.14.jar is a combined JAR file for 2.1.14
- jsf-api-2.2.0-m05.jar and jsf-impl-2.2.0-m05.jar are separate JARs for 2.2.0-m05.

The differences between the versions can be found in the release notes, but 2.2 and 2.1 are non-trivially different.