# Mocking the UIInput class for tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, jsf, mockito

I am trying to mock javax.faces.component.UIInput class.

My class is as below

```
public class MyBean{

    private UIInput someInput;  

   //setters and getters

}
```

**Test case**

```
UIInput mockedVale = Mockito.mock(UIInput.class);
MyBean myBean = new MyBean();
myBean.setSomeInput(mockedVale);
```

Can some one help me to fix this

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor3.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:45)
    at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.newInstance(ObjenesisBase.java:73)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxy(ClassImposterizer.java:142)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:61)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:52)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.CglibMockMaker.createMock(CglibMockMaker.java:24)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:32)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:59)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1258)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1135)
    at se.telenor.ocfd.web.facade.MyBean.<init>(MyBean.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find javax.faces.LogStrings bundle
    at java.util.logging.Logger.setupResourceInfo(Logger.java:1945)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:380)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.demandLogger(LogManager.java:554)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:455)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:553)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.<clinit>(UIComponent.java:116)
    ... 35 more
```

Answer (score 5):

In the class `UIComponent` (which your test uses), there's a static line for initializing the `Logger`:

```
private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("javax.faces.component",
    "javax.faces.LogStrings");
```

This means, the class is looking for a *resource bundle* named **LogStrings** within the package *javax.faces*. In the `javax.faces-2.2.11.jar` there's the directory *javax* and the subdirectory *faces* and within it the file **LogStrings.properties**. So your Class is also looking for this file.

Is the faces-jar within your classpath?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to bother with another dependency just because of testing using mock objects, you can simply put empty properties file into

```
testResourceDirectory/javax/faces/LogStrings.properties
```

and mocking of UIComponent won't be problem anymore.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [Niklas P.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32055683/mocking-the-uiinput-class-for-tests/32057485#32057485), the cause of the problem is the `Logger` initialization by `UIComponent`.

To solve the problem `jsf-api-xxx.jar` must be included in your project. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15562266/5078385) about using `jsf-api-xxx.jar` or `javax.faces-xxx.jar` (portability reasons):

> Actually you can use both. But the recommended way is to include `jsf-api-xxx.jar` only in the compilation classpath.

In Maven you just need to add the following dependency to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.8-18</version><!-- the version you are using -->
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: For whatever reason Oracle does not include the _LogStrings_ resource bundle within it's `javax:javaee-api:7.0` jar (it _is_ included in the sources jar! dooh!). The only way to get this to work is to include the `jsf-api-xxx.jar` as mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

I used this additional test-scoped Maven dependency (`pom.xml`):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```